# Click button after it is visible in Selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to emulate a search using Python and Selenium, but recently I faced a problem, when a button is generated but a JS. Here, in the picture below, the button Im t rying to click is "Save..." and it is visible (and clickable) after search is finished. Using code analyzer in Firefox, I found that this button's code is:

```
  <div class="pharmit_minbottom">
   <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">
    <span class="ui-button-text-only">
     Save...
    </span>
   </button>
  </div>
```

But in this code there are two more buttons with the same text label:

```
<div class="pharmit_resfooter">
  <div class="pharmit_bottomloaders pharmit_nowrap">
   <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled ui-button-text-only" disabled="" role="button">
    <span class="ui-button-text">
     Minimize
    </span>
   </button>
   <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled ui-button-text-only" disabled="" role="button">
    <span class="ui-button-text">
     Save...
    </span>
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I tried to click it using two different pieces of code:

```
time.sleep(30) #wait for the search to finish
driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-button-text-only').click()
```

And another one:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,'ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-button-text-only')))
wait.click()
```

But neither of them seems to work. how can I overcome this situation and finally click this button?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code:

**Using WebDriverWait:** (helps to avoid sleep in case of slow loading)

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
saveButton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='pharmit_‌​bottomloaders pharmit_nowrap']/button[2]/span")))
saveButton.click()
```

**Without WebDriverWait:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pharmit_‌​bottomloaders pharmit_nowrap']/button[2]/span").click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the replie, but Im still getting 'ElementNotVisibleException' as this button is not even loaded. Maybe, I need to somehow get my new page after perfoming search to the driver itself?

Comment: Always use `WebDriverWait` solution. what is the error with using first solution? TimeOutException?

Comment: Yep, TimeOutException.

Comment: what's your observation? Does the element is displayed? or not displayed?  when the exception raised? If not displayed, then increase the timeout from `30` to `60` seconds.

Comment: It is displayed even after 15 seconds and I can manually click on it. But the  program thinks that it is still invisible.

Comment: please add a screenshot of the element highlighting the `Save..` and its HTML code using Firefox `Inspect Element`.

Comment: updated the answer. please try out. IN the question, you have highlighted some other HTML code for the element you want to click. In the image shared in the comment, some other HTML code is shown, so updated the locator XPATH.

Comment: Still getting 'TimeOutException'. Using the second approach, I get 'Unable to locate element: //div[@class='pharmit_resfooter']/button[2]/span'

Comment: THANKS. This one is working.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pharmit_bottomloaders pharmit_nowrap']/button[2]/span").click()

Comment: updated the final answer. next time, please share the relevant HTML code for the element you want to find ;) to save time for both.

Comment: Yep, sorry, it was my bad;)